# What's the effect called when vibrations move through a cable under tension?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

I'm not sure how to describe it, but there is a certain sound of vibrations through a tensioned cable, you might hear it as sound effects in a movie where cables are snapping, some have described it as a metal whipping sound. I'm pretty certain you can also make a similar sound with those toy thundertubes (a long thin spring attached to a tin can).

The beginning of this song has a similar effect, which is what piqued my curiosity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80TSLiJz31o

There is also this video of a guy flicking a tensioned cable, producing the sound: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRWA9EUItC4

I have quite a few questions about the physics of this effect:

1. Is the sound produced in the same way a string on an instrument makes sound? Is there a difference that makes it sound the way it does?
2. Is there a specific name for this sound or effect in cables?
3. I've noticed a very similar sound when the boston subway comes into the station, I'm not sure if it's the tracks or the vibration of the rails, or possibly echoing of the vibrations in the tunnel, could it be the same effect through a different medium?

Any insight would be really helpful and would satiate my curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: The first example is synthetic: it's some kind of synth blip through an echo box (as someone who makes such noises I'm reasonably sure about this).  The second is obviously real.  In general I think noises like this are made by systems where the fundamental frequency is a couple of Hz, so you're hearing the sound as individual pulses.  Why they sound like this (all the cool high-frequency stuff) I'm not sure, but a quite good example is a thing called a 'spring reverb' which was used to simulate reverberation and which tend to produce noises like this (I have too many spring reverb units).

Comment: Thanks for the info, spring reverb seems to be a good term for it. I think I'll have to record the subway sound sometime - I don't think the subway has a cable anywhere near, it uses a third rail for power.

Comment: I suspect the subway effect is due to the train driving the whole volume of station into oscillation at (again) a few Hz as it leaves the tunnel.  I've heard this in tube stations in London.